# Applying age function to data-frame column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe `df` with a column `date of birth`.  The head looks like:

```
    Date of birth
0      1957-04-30
1      1966-11-10
2      1966-11-10
3      NOT KNOWN
4      1958-10-28
5      1958-06-04
```

I also have a variable called `referencePeriodEndDate` which is a date in a `yyyy-mm-dd` format and for example looks like `2017-03-31`

I am trying to create a new column called `Age` which is the age of from the `Date of birth` upto the `referencePeriodEndDate`

so the function to apply to each row would looks like:

```
(`referencePeriodEndDate` - df["Date of birth"]) / 365.25
```

There is the potential for rows in the `Date of birth` column to be empty (`null`) or have the entry `'NOT KNOWN'` so I need to return the value `'NOT KNOWN'` to the effected `column` in the new Age column.

I have come up with the following but it refuses to work (or return an error)

```
    df["Age"].apply(lambda row: TimeCalc(df,referencePeriodEndDate) if row.notnull() else "NOT KNOWN")


def TimeCalc(rawDatabase,referencePeriodEndDate):

     Age = ((referencePeriodEndDate - rawDatabase["Date of birth"]) / 365.25)

     return Age
```

The desired output would look like:

```
 Date of birth            Age
    30/04/1957    59.91786448
    10/11/1966    50.38740589
    10/11/1966    50.38740589
     NOT KNOWN      NOT KNOWN
    28/10/1958    58.42299795
    04/06/1958    58.82272416
```

Comment: What does the error say?

Comment: Both `df["Date Of birth"]` and `referencePeriodEndDate` needs to be converted to `datetime` object first to calculate the difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can using`to_datetime`

```
df['Dateofbirth']=pd.to_datetime(df['Dateofbirth'],errors='coerce')
df['Age']=(pd.to_datetime('2017-03-31')-df['Dateofbirth']).dt.days/365.25

df.fillna('unknow')
Out[370]: 
           Dateofbirth      Age
0  1957-04-30 00:00:00  59.9179
1  1966-11-10 00:00:00  50.3874
2  1966-11-10 00:00:00  50.3874
3               unknow   unknow
4  1958-10-28 00:00:00   58.423
5  1958-06-04 00:00:00  58.8227
```